# My jquery code that I wrote to clean the inputs is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-5

I added the select-picker library to my @Html.DropDownListFors. After adding this everything changed. Currently, dropdown works fine, but I cannot clear the inputs when I close the modal.I don't get any errors in the console.

```
//CLEAN MODAL INPUTS
const myModalEl = document.getElementById('insertUpdateModal');
myModalEl.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', event => {
    $("#insertUpdateModal").find(".repair-inputs").val(null);
    $("#insertUpdateModal").find(".selectpicker").val(null);
    $("#crud_type").val(null);
});
```

Scripts :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.22.1/dist/bootstrap-table-locale-all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/repair.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

DropDownList :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Repairs.urunID, Model.ProductsList, "Lütfen Bir Ürün Seçiniz*", new { @class = "form-control repair-inputs selectpicker", id = "repairProductInput", required = "required", data_live_search="true"})
```

Comment: Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  If the problem is entirely in client-side code then you'll want to focus on that code, not on the server-side code which generates (and could be generating anything, we don't know).

Comment: I did not understand what you are trying to say. I thought of using Codepen, but I couldn't do it because my modal was ajax.beginform.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that if the problem is specifically happening in the browser (and not on the server) on a single page (no navigation to other pages) then it's specifically with regards to HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  If that's the case then you could take some time to create a runnable [mcve] which observably demonstrates the problem.  Currently we don't know what your HTML looks like.

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry, I'm a newbie. I understand what you mean and I think the problem is related to HTML/CSS/JavaScript as you said. But I can't show you this on codepen. And I think the problem lies more with libraries.